# Easiest way to specialize code to constants in Rust?

Tags: rust

Say I have a loop like this where `xs.len()` is huge and `order <= 3`:

```rust
pub fn cumulative_sum(xs: Vec<i64>, order: usize) {
  let mut res = Vec::with_capacity(xs.len());
  let mut moments = vec![0; order];
  for i in 0..xs.len() {
    res.push(moments[0]);
    for o in 0..order - 1 {
      moments[o] += moments[o + 1];
    }
    moments[order - 1] += xs[i];
  }
}
```

I find I can make this about 2x as fast by specializing with a compile-time constant for order, but my current code is rather unpleasant. Something like:

```rust
trait CompileTimeOrder {
  const ORDER: usize;
}

macro_rules! impl_order {
  ($name: ident, $order: expr) => {
    struct $name;
    impl CompileTimeOrder for $name {
      const ORDER: usize = $order;
    }
  }
}

impl_order!(Order1, 1);
impl_order!(Order2, 2);
impl_order!(Order3, 3);

fn cumulative_sum_internal<O: CompileTimeOrder>(xs: Vec<i64>) {
  let order = O::ORDER;
   ... // same logic as before
}

pub fn cumulative_sum(xs: Vec<i64>, order: usize) {
  match order {
    1 => cumulative_sum_internal::<Order1>(xs),
    2 => cumulative_sum_internal::<Order2>(xs),
    3 => cumulative_sum_internal::<Order3>(xs),
    _ => panic!()
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to specialize to particular values of order here?

Comment: If the function should panic if the `order` is not 1-3, does adding `assert!(order < 3)` grant you any performance gain? Otherwise there are different methods in [Optimize Rust function for certain likely parameter values](/q/75226210/2189130) Q&A but its mostly the same complexity as what you already have.

Comment: Interesting - just tried the `#[inline(always)]` trick, which gave the speedup with less code, but bloated the binary more. The `assert!` does not give me the performance gain.

Comment: I don't see how order being constant could really speed up anything here, look like premature optimization, specially when it's look you are learning rust

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6002d5d416c28c9e248d62f12fa34edb thus your algo is not clear for me

Comment: Did you `panic!()` on the non-three case with the `#[inline(always)]` trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a better to specialize to constant values!
[Const generics](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/03/25/Rust-1.51.0.html#const-generics-mvp) were released mid-2021 in Rust 1.51.

The improved version of my original code is simpler, achieves the same performance, and has a smaller binary size:

```rust
fn cumulative_sum_internal<const ORDER: usize>(xs: Vec<i64>) {
   ... // same logic as before
}

pub fn cumulative_sum(xs: Vec<i64>, order: usize) {
  match order {
    1 => cumulative_sum_internal::<1>(xs),
    2 => cumulative_sum_internal::<2>(xs),
    3 => cumulative_sum_internal::<3>(xs),
    _ => panic!()
  }
}
```